C++ for loop tests being incorrectly optimized out
Inside the constructor for an overloaded, templated class, I have the following for loop. The original loop was more complicated, but I removed all the variables besides x that were doing useful computation during debugging to get a minimal example inside the larger structure. This is what is currently there:
for (int x = 8-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
    std::cout << x << "-";
    if (x < 0) break;
}

When I run this, it prints: 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10--11- (...)
And the debugger shows the disassembly (ARM) to be:
    0x102aeef74 <+100>: mov    x0, x19
    0x102aeef78 <+104>: mov    x1, x20
    0x102aeef7c <+108>: bl     0x102bbb1f4               ; symbol stub for: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(int)
    0x102aeef80 <+112>: mov    x1, x21
    0x102aeef84 <+116>: mov    w2, #0x1
    0x102aeef88 <+120>: bl     0x102acfbc8               ; std::__1::__put_character_sequence[abi:v160006]<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>> at ostream:753
    0x102aeef8c <+124>: sub    w20, w20, #0x1
->  0x102aeef90 <+128>: b      0x102aeef74               ; <+100> at LexPermutationPDB.h:108:13

It appears that the loop conditions are being optimized away. If you extract the code out of the context (eg put just the loop in main), it works fine. My guess is that there is undefined behavior somewhere that is leading to a bad optimization.
I'm running Xcode Version 15.2 (15C500b) in MacOS Ventura with code in Release mode, which is -Os.
The error appeared when adding a new class that inherits from the class where the problem occurs. The new class overloads a single function and uses a different constructor. This error is coming while calling the constructor, but after the parent classes have already been initialized.
I was going to try a different compiler, but are there other ideas on how to track down what is going wrong? Perhaps something has already been fixed in a newer version of the compiler.
--Update--
Here is a minimal working example of the failure:
% cat test.cpp                 
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <int width, int height>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        Reset();
    }
    void Reset()
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < size(); x++)
            puzzle[x] = x;
    }
    size_t size() const { return width*height; }
    std::array<int, width*height> puzzle;
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass<4, 4> s;
    for (int x = 7; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        if (x < 0) break;
        std::cout << x << "-";
    }
    //std::fill(s.puzzle.begin(), s.puzzle.end(), -1);
    std::fill(&s.puzzle[0], &s.puzzle[s.size()], -1);
}
% g++ -std=gnu++17 -Os test.cpp
% ./a.out                      
7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10 (...)

Compiled with
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0
Thread model: posix


When I run this We also want to run this. A [mre] should be provided.

Putting that inside int main(){}, I can't reproduce it with mainline Clang 18.1 for x86-64 Linux.  https://godbolt.org/z/qG9a8s6c1 .  And unfortunately Godbolt's clang install doesn't have headers that work for -target arm64-apple-darwin -stdlib=libc++ cross-compiling for macOS from Linux.  Replacing cout << x with foo(x) with a function I only gave a prototype for, I get a normal-looking loop: https://godbolt.org/z/15xajz6sn

This is in a reasonably complex class hierarchy with templates and inheritance, but I'll work on removing more things to see if I can narrow down the issue so I can get a smaller example than the original code.

Generally, the weirder the result the more you need to provide a [mre] (MRE) that reproduces the problem. What we can't reproduce, we can't help you fix, and If it turns out you've stumbled into a compiler bug you'll need the MRE to hand over to the dev team with the bug report so they can reproduce and fix it.

Does the problem happen if you remove if (x < 0) break;? That condition can never succeed, because the loop stops after x == 0

If that fixes it, it sounds like an optimizer bug. It realizes that condition will never break, and for some reason it also removes the for condition.

Is it possible that the code which follows the loop causes undefined behavior? If so, the compiler may assume that it's unreachable, and deduce that the loop termination condition must always be false. And that would be perfectly legal for it to do.

Could it be that x is actually unsigned?

@Eljay unlikely because the printout shows negative numbers

Is there anything else in the loop? Is x an index for array. This is typical "extreme optimization" gcc would do if there is UB on "last" iteration , e.g. going out of (visible) bounds. Usually you can see warning about that, unless that particular warning is off.

@Barmar Yes - I added that line to further verify the issue.

@Swift-FridayPie No. There was other code but I commented it all out and still got the issue.

@NateEldredge Yes! This looks like the right direction. I commented out the following code in the procedure and the problem went away.

@3CxEZiVlQ A minimal reproducible example is now in the question.

The clue came from a comment by Nate Eldredge in the comments. The line following the for loop was:
std::fill(&s.puzzle[0], &s.puzzle[s.size()], -1);
which should be:
std::fill(s.puzzle.begin(), s.puzzle.end(), -1);
Note that this works as well:
std::fill(&s.puzzle[0], &s.puzzle[s.size()-1]+1, -1);
The first line accesses beyond the end of the array, which was causing undefined behavior, and thus allowing the for loop to be optimized incorrectly. (Note that both versions of the code work properly on a bunch of different compilers. Without looking at the C++ standard it's unclear to me whether this is a bug or something I was unaware of in the standard.)
Lesson: Even though the issue was manifesting itself in the for loop, I should have looked for errors in code after where the apparent issue was occurring. (The fact that no code was showing after the loop in the assembly was a hint that it had been optimized out, which I missed.)

odd that it didn't produce warning, is that how clang still rolls? GCC warns if it does this

Is that really UB though? I thought it was legitimate to create a pointer to "the element after" the end of an array, provided that you do not deference it. I suppose the code looks syntactically as if it does, even though the & operator means it semantically doesn't. Is this a counterexample to the rule of thumb that &* is a no-op?

@NateEldredge: s.puzzle must be a std::vector or std::array or other container to support .size() and .end(), so its operator[] function probably returns a reference, which probably has to be a real object.  Taking the address of the referenced object is "too late" to cancel it out, I think.  Or if that's supposed to be safe for standard containers, maybe it's the OP's custom class.

@Swift-FridayPie I'd hope it would at least warn with -Wall, but maybe not.  You might have to disable optimization and use -fsanitize=undefined to avoid the loop becoming infinite and have execution actually reach the UB with extra code inserted by the sanitizer.  OTOH, I still can't reproduce this with mainline clang 18 using a std::vector<int> with vec.size() as the size.  https://godbolt.org/z/Yhzrx3f4r The OP seems to be using a separate size, s.size() which isn't just the size of the container (which would be s.puzzle.size()).

@PeterCordes s.puzzle is a std::array. In this context s.size() is the same as s.puzzle.size(). I'll have to see if I can reproduce this outside of this context - there could still be something else going on.

@PeterCordes I've updated the question with a fully working example and all the details needed to reproduce.

@NathanS.: Ok, yes, finally that triggers -fsanitize=undefined when optimization is enabled.  (I'd first tested with -O0 and that wasn't triggering, but with your -Os it does).  On x86-64 clang with -stdlib=libc++ -  https://godbolt.org/z/95KhKzqM1 .  UBSAN catches the problem with both the Linux default libstdc++ and with -stdlib=libc++.  But without UBSAN it prints the "expected" output, not optimizing the way that version of AArch64 Apple Clang does.
